# Restore MySQL from files (without dump)

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to duplicate a MySQL database from their files? [I know mysqldump would be the best method to duplicate a db, but that's not possible as all we have is the backed up files from the mysql folder].

We have the ibdata1 file, the ib_log* files, and the full directories for the three db's we want to restore from the backed up files (folders seem to contain all needed frm and par files). Obviously already tried just to copy all the files into /var/lib/mysql and though it appeared the structure was intact attempts to access the data were unsuccessful.

i.e. `show databases` will show the db's, `use dbname` works, and `show tables` properly displays the tables, but when trying to access the data from [any] table (via query) it says **ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'dbname.dbtable' doesn't exist** - despite mysql having happily showed us the table does exist when we did show tables.

Should also point out the service was stopped prior to copying files and all files chown'ed to have mysql as owner and then the service restarted prior to attempting to access the data.

Comment: Do you see anything in the MySQL server error logs? InnoDB can be rather finicky to recover data from. You'll at least need to make sure the server configs match for the important variables like InnoDB logfile size, etc.

Comment: Error it gives is: 120326 10:07:18 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table dbname/tablename from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.

But looks like Jaydee provided a link that may shed some light on how to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question indirectly, there is some information here regarding setting up replication using a raw file copy. So I guess the answer is possibly yes, but it may depend.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-rawdata.html

Not wishing to add to your current pain, but were you relying on a backup that you have never tried / don't know how to restore?

Comment: The link looks helpful, thanks. As for the backup plan I didn't want to clutter up my question with needless backstory. I use mysqldump regularly...to make a long story short this db in question didn't have a recent dump due to human error, but we did a full DD of the drive before wiping it.

Comment: So are you using the exact same MySQL and InnoDB versions as well as config files?

Comment: Ok, that explains it. Good luck with the recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have just copied the content of /var/lib/mysql and it works. Maybe you need to try the new version of MySQL. I usually do this operations within docker for my internal dev purposes.